# Submit a textbox by pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, form-submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bind textbox to 'enter' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943954/bind-textbox-to-enter-key)

I have a search text box. I would like to get it submitted while pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key (when that text box is focused only). I am not using any submit button. Can this be accomplished using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Bind textbox to 'enter' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943954/bind-textbox-to-enter-key)
and `form.submit()` method.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the `<input>` tag is inside a `<form>` tag, the form will be submitted automatically when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from within the text field.  This is default behavior on all web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can implement that using javascript. Write a javascript funciton and call it when you click the button. Using **form.yourTextBoxId**  you can get the value from the text box.