# Javascript submit textbox on ENTER

Tags: javascript, submit, enter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Bind textbox to 'enter' key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943954/bind-textbox-to-enter-key)

I've made a chat system with AJAX and jQuery and there is no `<form>` tag wrapping the TextBox for chat messages, so I can't submit that message with the `ENTER` button on the keyboard.

Is there any way I can submit that value from TextBox with javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("id_of_your_textbox").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (!e) { var e = window.event; }
    e.preventDefault(); // sometimes useful

    // Enter is pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { submitFunction(); }
}, false);
```

Comment: if you're using a function to do something else like I was remember to throw an e.preventDefault(); in before the function call to prevent the form being submitted.

Comment: The original prevents me from typing anything into the box, edited to make it work proper.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#textboxId').keydown(function (event) {
    let keyPressed = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keyPressed === 13) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
});
```

If you don't have form, then replace `$(this).closest('form').submit();` with whatever AJAX/submit logic you have.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen for the ENTER key press event.  Take a look at [Enter key press event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/javascriptenter-key-press-event) for some examples on how it is done.